# SQL Query Conditional Select based on Newer Entry

Tags: sql

I have a query which searches a database of tests for failed tests and returns a certain code if there is a failure for a specific set of tests.  What I need for it to do, is to only return that code if there is not a newer version of that test saved in the database that has passed.  This is part of a set of queries that, given a certain project number, query every subset of that number (there are 5 test subsets), and then check and give it one of 4 different statuses.  Here is an excerpt:

```
SELECT
MAX(
CASE
WHEN PROJECT.PARENT_ID IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM TESTRESULTS WHERE TESTRESULTS.RESULTID = '962'))) 
AND PROJECT.PROJECTNAME LIKE '%EMC%' 
THEN '4'
ELSE.....
```

I need to check the same table for newer entries with the same name, that belong to the same project, that have passed their tests instead of failed, ie RESULTID = '961', and instead let it fall through to the other cases, rather than assign it a '4'.  The dates of the tests are stored in the table.  I've played with this a while on my own, doing some joins from the table back onto itself, but this parent's parent's parent's hierarchy is making it difficult to say the least.  Also, I did not design this database and don't have the ability to alter the schema in any way.

Edit:
This is the relevant structure of the table, and some example records:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | TEST TYPE | RESULTID | TESTDATE
-------------------------------------------------
4  |     1     | ESD       |   962    | 01-01-11
5  |     2     | CI        |   961    | 01-02-11
6  |     3     | ESD       |   961    | 02-01-11
7  |     8     | RI        |   962    | 02-02-11
```

I need a query that will return tests that fail (resultid 962) unless there is another test with the same name, and the same parent_id relationship described in the query above, but that passed the test (resultid 961).  So, if I ran the query on 01-01-11, I would get the row with ID of 4, but if I ran it on 02-01-11, it would return no rows, and on 02-02-11 it would return the row with ID of 7.  Also, there are resultids > 962 for anomalies, etc. and a resultid < 961 for tests that haven't taken place yet.

Edit again:  Object Table structure

```
ID | PARENT_ID | Description   |
--------------------------------
50 |     0     | Product Level | (Very Top)
51 |    50     | Project Level | (The PROJECT table describes this lvl)
52 |    51     | Work Request  |
1  |    52     | Work Order    |
2  |    52     | Work Order    |
3  |    52     | Work Order    |
8  |    52     | Work Order    |
```

So, referencing the table above, each test in the TESTRESULT table is a child of a worker, which is in turn the child of a work request, which is the child of a project, which is the child of a product.  I need to be able to tie every individual test result back to the project level, which is why I am running everything up to the PROJECT table, rather than the work request table.

Comment: Data structures and sample records?

Comment: Which database. If its oracle, then there is an easy way to handle parent hierarchy like this using Connect By Prior.

Comment: it is using interbase, and to get an accurate idea of the data structure, id have to show several sample records, and i dont have the time to anonymize enough of them, but a basic idea is this:
object table contains every object (project, test set, test, work order, etc), and there are several attribute tables, which hold information relating to an object, linked by the object id.  objects also have other objects as their parents, so theres a parent object, a product, and then it has several child objects which in turn can have several of their own, as well as attributes in other tables

Comment: I'd like to help, but I honestly can't follow your request.  Consider spelling things out in a little more detail, remembering that us here on SO don't know anything about your data or your expected output except what you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the query (for reference, the original answer is below).

```
WHEN PROJECT.PARENT_ID IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM TESTRESULTS t1 WHERE t1.RESULTID = '962'
and not exists 
(select * from object o2 
WHERE PROJECT.PARENT_ID = o2.id and o2.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM object WHERE object.id IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM TESTRESULTS t2 WHERE t2.RESULTID = '961'
and t1.testtype = t2.testtype and t2.testdate > t1.testdate)))))))
AND PROJECT.PROJECTNAME LIKE '%EMC%'
```

Test scenario to reach that result:

```
create table #tmpObj (ident int primary key, parent_id int, description varchar(20));
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (50, 0, 'Product Level');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (60, 50, 'Project X');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (70, 60, 'Work request 1');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (101, 70, 'Work order 1a');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (102, 70, 'Work order 1b');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (103, 70, 'Work order 1c');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (71, 60, 'Work request 2');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (111, 71, 'Work order 2a');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (112, 71, 'Work order 2b');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (113, 71, 'Work order 2c');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (61, 50, 'Project Z');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (80, 61, 'Work request 1');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (201, 80, 'Work order 1a');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (202, 80, 'Work order 1b');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (203, 80, 'Work order 1c');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (81, 61, 'Work request 2');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (211, 81, 'Work order 2a');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (212, 81, 'Work order 2b');
insert into #tmpObj (ident, parent_id, description) values (213, 81, 'Work order 2c');

create table #tmpTest (ident int primary key, parent_id int, name1 varchar(10), resultid int, testdate date);
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2001, 101, 'ESD', 962, '2011-01-01');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2002, 102, 'CI', 961, '2011-01-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2003, 103, 'RI', 961, '2011-01-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2004, 111, 'ESD', 961, '2011-02-01');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2005, 112, 'CI', 962, '2011-02-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2006, 113, 'RI', 961, '2011-02-03');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2007, 201, 'ESD', 961, '2011-01-01');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2008, 202, 'CI', 961, '2011-01-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (2009, 203, 'RI', 961, '2011-01-02');

SELECT * FROM #tmpObj o1 WHERE o1.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpObj WHERE #tmpObj.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpObj WHERE #tmpObj.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpTest t1 WHERE t1.RESULTID = 962
and not exists 
(select * from #tmpObj o2 
WHERE o1.ident = o2.ident and o2.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpObj WHERE #tmpObj.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpObj WHERE #tmpObj.ident IN
(SELECT parent_id FROM #tmpTest t2 WHERE t2.RESULTID = 961
and t1.name1 = t2.name1 and t2.testdate > t1.testdate)))))));
```

---

Original answer:

Well, the given information confuses me a little, but it seems as if this calls for an EXISTS() subquery (I hope that is available in interbase), like the following (simplified, without the parent-parent stuff) example:

```
create table #tmpTest (ident int primary key, parent_id int, name1 varchar(10), resultid int, testdate date);
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (4, 1, 'ESD', 962, '2011-01-01');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (5, 2, 'CI', 961, '2011-01-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (6, 1, 'ESD', 961, '2011-02-01');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (7, 8, 'RI', 962, '2011-02-02');
insert into #tmpTest (ident, parent_id, name1, resultid, testdate) values (9, 8, 'RI', 962, '2011-02-03');

select * from #tmpTest t1 
where resultid = 962 and not exists 
(select ident from #tmpTest t2 
where t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id 
and t2.resultid = 961 
and t2.testdate > t1.testdate);
```

I assumed that the parent_id in your testresults table can be used to identify the test category, but that may not be accurate.
I hope this will at least help you to refine your query.

Comment: The problem with that is that the parent_id of a failure is not the same as its repeat.  It's organized into a tree-ish structure, and the tests have a work order as their parents, and every new test is a new work order.  I will add in the structure of the object table so that it may make a little bit more sense.

Comment: @TheJubilex I rewrote my answer. It should be much closer to what you need. Btw, your `PROJECT.PARENT_ID` references `OBJECT.ID`, right?